# Removing '-' from negative Joda time Periods

Tags: java, date, jodatime, subtraction

I have a question regarding subtracting Joda DateTimes, and I use Period to get number of dates, hours, minutes and seconds between the two.

Output example : 2 days 11h 23min 05sec

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
DateTime firstDate = formatter.parseDateTime(firstStringDateValue);
DateTime secondDate = formatter.parseDateTime(secondStringDateValue);

DurationFieldType[] types = {DurationFieldType.days(), 
                             DurationFieldType.hours(), 
                             DurationFieldType.minutes(), 
                             DurationFieldType.seconds()};

Period period = new Period(firstDate, secondDate, PeriodType.forFields(types));

PeriodFormatter periodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
            .appendDays().appendSuffix(" Day", " Days").appendSeparator(" ")
            .appendHours().appendSuffix("h").appendSeparator(" ")
            .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("min").appendSeparator(" ")
            .appendSeconds().appendSuffix("sec")
            .toFormatter();

String result = periodFormatter.print(period);
```

The problem is when the start the date is greater than the end date.

The result is something like this : -2 days -11h -23min -05sec

So I was wondering is there a way to make it look like this : - 2 days 11h 23min 05sec, with only one '-' in front of the whole thing. But using Joda related functions.

Or at least a method to tell me if the Period is negative.

I can do this using string manipulation but it seems a bit too manual.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is comparing two date.

There are [isAfter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#isAfter%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) and [isBefore](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#isBefore%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) methods that compare dates by millis (ignoring time zone).

```
firstDate.isBefore(secondDate)
firstDate.isAfter(secondDate)
```

Now, you can set parameters in the correct order.
Then, add the leading minus if needed.

Comment: I see, I can use this to control parameter order in the Period constructor and add '+' or '-' accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, [`Period`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) has no method `abs()` in comparison with [`Duration`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html#abs--).

However, we can write our own helper-method to achieve this with help of [`Period::negated()`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#negated--) method:

```java
public static Period periodAbs(Period period) {
    return period.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds() < 0
        ? period.negated()
        : period;
}
```

Furthermore, you can extract this logic to separate class (that's definitely better choice in my opinion) if you don't like static methods :

```java
public static class AbsPeriod {
    private final Period period;

    public AbsPeriod(Period period) {
        this.period = period;
    }

    public Period value() {
        return period.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds() < 0
            ? period.negated()
            : period;
    }
}
```

Complete runnable example:

```java
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DurationFieldType;
import org.joda.time.Period;
import org.joda.time.PeriodType;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        DateTime firstDate = formatter.parseDateTime("12/11/2001 12:12:12");
        DateTime secondDate = formatter.parseDateTime("12/11/2000 12:12:12");

        DurationFieldType[] types = {DurationFieldType.days(),
            DurationFieldType.hours(),
            DurationFieldType.minutes(),
            DurationFieldType.seconds()};

        Period period = new Period(firstDate, secondDate, PeriodType.forFields(types));

        PeriodFormatter periodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
            .appendDays().appendSuffix(" Day", " Days").appendSeparator(" ")
            .appendHours().appendSuffix("h").appendSeparator(" ")
            .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("min").appendSeparator(" ")
            .appendSeconds().appendSuffix("sec")
            .toFormatter();

        System.out.println("original period = " + periodFormatter.print(period));
        System.out.println("absolute period = " + periodFormatter.print(new AbsPeriod(period).value()));
    }

    public static class AbsPeriod {
        private final Period period;

        public AbsPeriod(Period period) {
            this.period = period;
        }

        public Period value() {
            return period.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds() < 0
                ? period.negated()
                : period;
        }
    }
}
```

And corresponding STDOUT produced by this test-snippet:

```
original period = -365 Days
absolute period = 365 Days
```

Comment: This does seem to be simpler to understand than putting a condition over the constructor, I'll be combining this with the previous answer. Thank you